# why doesnt new_session shared_ptr not get destroyed here?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<chat_session> chat_session_ptr;



  void start_accept()
      {
        chat_session_ptr new_session(new chat_session(io_service_, room_));
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
            boost::bind(&chat_server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }

void handle_accept(chat_session_ptr session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      session->start();
    }

    start_accept();
```

Why doesnt the `new_session` shared ptr get destroyed? If I understand correctly the `acceptor_.async_accept` returns immediately as its a asynchronous calls?  so wont the shared ptr get deleted when the `start_accept` function returns.

and as new_session class has a socket member, the sockets lifetime is bound with this new_session, and so the ability to read and write tcp messages also? isnt it?

----edit---
based on Billy ONeal's answer : I have a further question

so new_session will exist forever unless an error occurs or I close the server forcefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `chat_session` lives as long as it's "active", i.e. no error occurs. Its life-cycle can be divided into 2 parts:

1) Before its `start` member function is called, `chat_session` instance is kept alive because `shared_ptr<chat_session>` is bound to the completion handler of the `acceptor_`. When completion handler gets invoked, it's removed from `io_service` queue and destroyed - with its `shared_ptr<chat_session>`. However, if a connection was accepted successfully, the completion handler starts the second phase:

2) When `chat_session::start` is called, `chat_session` registers itself in a `chat_room` manager

```
room_.join(shared_from_this());
```

which stores a `shared_ptr<chat_session>` in some container. This `shared_ptr` is removed from the container in `chat_session::start`, which is called on error.

(Actually, even without this registration, `chat_session` would be kept alive due to the `shared_from_this` idiom used with every async. operation.)

Answer (score 0):

`boost::bind` returns a function object which contains a copy of the referenced `shared_ptr`, in this case `new_session`. `async_accept` may be asynchronous, but it needs to store a copy of the target function object so that function can be called when the asynchronous request completes.

Comment: so new_session will exist forever unless an error occurs or I close the server forcefully?

Comment: It probably lives as long as acceptor_; but I'm no asio expert. This answer is based on how all callback based APIs have to work.